# submit spark program from code,and that job not shown on history server ui

Tags: java, apache-spark, submit

When I submit a spark job from command line, the job will appear on both spark history server UI and hadoop resource manager UI, but when I submit from java code, job is shown on hadoop resource manager UI but not on spark history server UI.

The spark program is the same, only the way I'm submitting it is not.

Submit code :

```
public class submitJava {
    public static Map getPropXmlAsMap(String path) throws Exception, IOException{
        File file = new File(path);
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.build(file);
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        List props = root.getChildren("property");
        Map result = new HashMap();
        for(Iterator iter = props.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
            Element element = (Element) iter.next();
            Element nameele = element.getChild("name");
            Element valueele = element.getChild("value");
            String name = nameele.getText();
            String value = valueele.getText();
            result.put(name, value);
        }
        return result;

    }
    public static void fillProperties(Configuration conf,Map map){
        Iterator iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
            String key = (String)entry.getKey();
            String value = (String)entry.getValue();
            conf.set(key, value);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

        sparkConf.setMaster("yarn-cluster");


        try {
            fillProperties(config,getPropXmlAsMap("/home/tseg/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
            fillProperties(config,getPropXmlAsMap("/home/tseg/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml"));

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<String> runArgs = Arrays.asList(
                "--class","org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi",
                "--addJars","hdfs://tseg0:9010/user/tseg/hh/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar",
                "--jar","file:////home/tseg/hh/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.0/lib/spark-examples-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar"
                ,"--arg","10"
                );

        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");

        ClientArguments argss = new ClientArguments(runArgs.toArray(new String[runArgs.size()]),sparkConf);

        Client client = new Client(argss,config,sparkConf);

        ApplicationId applicationId = client.submitApplication();


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/running-on-yarn.html

It states that there is a property `spark.yarn.historyServer.address` which defaults to empty since the history server is an optional service. Probably it is not getting set when you submit from code, but is set when you launch via the command line.